# Php sessions appear to get dropped/lost on regeneration

Tags: php, session, authentication, authorization

I'm using 24 hour sessions at the moment to keep users logged in, if they browse to another page of the site after 30 minutes of the session starting then the session will be regenerated to extend the session expiration time to time() + 24 hours.

I am using php.ini to ensure only cookie sessions are used and altered their default save time to just over 24 hours:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 90000
session.cookie_lifetime = 90000
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.use_only_cookies = 1
```

I use the following to being a session:

```
session_save_path("/home/user/sessions");
session_set_cookie_params("86400", "/");
session_name("auth");
session_start();
```

but at the moment my sessions seem to get lost within the first hour. The cookie `auth` is still there but it doesn't seem to link to the information that was stored when the session was made:

```
$_SESSION['userId'] = $row[0];
$_SESSION['created'] = time();
```

This leads me to think that the regeneration part is somehow incorrect?

To regenerate a cookie after 30 minutes I am using:

```
if($_SESSION['created'] + 30 * 60 < time())
{
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['created'] = time();
}
```

Does the above code need to have some way to keep the session id after regeneration?

Like:

```
$sid = session_id();
session_regenerate_id();
session_id($sid);
session_start();
```

or is this not necessary? Are there any other reasons my sessions could be getting lost/mixed up?

Comment: The whole idea of session_regenerate_id is to recreate the session with a new id. So after a session_regenerate_id() I would not use the 'old' session id anymore.

Comment: ah I see, I wasn't meaning to pass the old id I was more hoping to keep the data from the old session but I guess it does? I've just noticed my php.ini file is being ignored for some reason so this could have something to do with it? Although the session cookies have expire values of over 24 hours so must be a cron deleting the files somehow.

Comment: I would try setting your 'regenerate time' to a low value (e.g. 60 seconds) and then check that the cookies are set/reset with the correct expire dates by inspecting the cookies themselves in your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session lifetimes are (usually) dependable. But since you mention that they seem to be getting wiped out within an hour, it makes me think that the server is running a debian or debian derived OS.

On our server (running ubuntu 10.10), sessions get cleaned out every half-an-hour by the system through a cron job, whether or not the session is still valid. The only way around it is by creating your own session handler.

If the server is not debian based, then I'd have to say I don't know.

Comment: This was my first guess too, your session files are probably deleted. This is not debian-specific, you might have this problem on other distributions too. However I suggest editing the cron job rather than writing a custom session handler.

Comment: Where abouts do you find system cron jobs? I've only ever looked at those in cpanel

Comment: Usually in /etc/cron.[d|hourly|daily|weekly|monthly] Might be different on other distributions though.

Comment: It's running centOS, a `crontab -e` shows the crons setup but I'm not sure which does which

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think that's the one we need. Check out the cron directories in /etc. I'm sure something will jump out at you. In ubuntu, the main crontab runs several others located in /etc/cron.d, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.hourly etc.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, when a session is created it stores a session file in the temporary folder on the server, if this file is deleted or removed then the session would be lost, could this be happening?

A work around for this would be to set a cookie valid for 24 hours with a unique pair of values that you can store against a user, that way when they return if the session has been destroyed they will still be logged in as the script would match the data from the cookies to the data held in the database.

What information are you storing in the session as this would also be lost.

Comment: You could do that but it would be less secure and easier for hackers to gain entry via brute forcing the hashed values in the cookie? That's why I'm using sessions to keep ensure no secure unique values are ever shown to users.

Comment: to an extent you are correct but what stops the hacker from hijacking the session to start with?  If they can hack the cookie data then they can easily hijack the session!

Comment: How? Cookies are stored on their computer so easy to edit the values whereas sessions are stored on the server and regenerated within 30 minutes with sha512 id's.

Comment: The session data is stored on the server but the cookie for the session is stored on the local machine, I have many times hijacked sessions that do not operate over https just be acquiring the local session cookie.

If the cookie had two values it had to match that where 64bit in length the chances of them just changing both values and gaining access is highly unlikely, you would also implement a server protection on this with multiple different attempts from the same source.